# Android Push event handler is not called if app is running in foreground

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/ for push notification.

```
pushRegistry = window.PushNotification.init({
      android: {
          'senderID': 'appId'
      },
      ios: {
          alert: 'true',      
          badge: 'false',     
          sound: 'true'       
      }
});
pushRegistry.on('notification', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Now above event handler is invoked when a notification is received and app is closed. But it is not invoked if the app is running. I am using Chrome Device Debugger to check if event handler is invoked. I will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Do you really mean that `console.log(data)` above or the toast notification actually?